# Does solr support the sorting while creating index?

Tags: performance, solr, indexing

In my test environment, there are nearly 130,000,000 documents on each server. It works fast if I do a search without sorting by date, but extremly slow if sorting is enabled.

I think if the solr can sort an indexed field while creating index, searching would be more efficient. So, how to configure the solr to sort some fields while indexing?

Comment: You didn't say if you've indexed the documents using solr. You might also want to give a bit of context of the kind of queries you'll like to perform on the documents.

Comment: I have indexed all the 130,000,000 docs by solr. All of them are full-text doc, and our queries are simple - get the latest 6 docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial query would be slower but all the subsequent queries should be fast.
Solr should be able to use the [Filter Query Cache for sorting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache).

You can also [warm the sort fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#Explicit_Warming_of_Sort_Fields).
Also check if the overhead is also just cause of sorting and there is no querying and scoring involved.